gatling-maven-plugin exits without doing cleanup in case of assetion failure
I am trying to run Gatling for a Spring boot app with maven build and starting the app before the test starts and stopping the app after the test. Problem which I am facing is that if there are any assertion failures post steps like stopping the app is not happing.
When it is passing everything is runing fine. Starting the app using spring-boot-maven-plugin and starting stopping using
               <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

